# Google SpreadsheetでQuery関数、Importrange関数を組み合わせる

Tags: google-spreadsheet

二つのGoogle Spreadsheetがあり、IMPORTRANGEとQuery関数を利用して、片方からもう片方へSUMしつつデータを表示させたいです。

Spreadsheet 1

| ID | Name | Sales | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | aa | 687 | 4 |
| 345 | bb | 8987 | 4 |
| 123 | aa | 717 | 5 |
| 345 | bb | 1115 | 4 |

Spreadsheet 2 Before

| ID | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 123 |  |
| 345 |  |

Spreadsheet 2 After

| ID | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 687 |
| 345 | 10102 |

Spreadsheet 2

```
B2=query(importrange("Spreadsheet 1 URL","xxx!A:D"), "SELECT SUM(Col3) where Col1='"&A2&"' and Col4 = 4")
```

このように関数を記載するとなぜかB2の中にカラム名のようなものが入ってしまい、
以下のように表示されてしまいます。687というSUM結果は正しいのですが行自体もずれてしまいます。
カラム名を消す方法ありますでしょうか。

Spreadsheet 2 After

| ID | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | sum Sales |
| 345 | 687 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> このように関数を記載するとなぜかB2の中にカラム名のようなものが入ってしまい、

[QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) によると

> クエリ言語について詳しくは、https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

また, その [Query Language Reference (Version 0.7)](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) によると, `label` が該当します

> label
> Sets column labels.

具体的には以下で可能なはず

```
"SELECT SUM(Col3) where Col1='"&A2&"' and Col4 = 4"
    
"SELECT SUM(Col3) where Col1='"&A2&"' and Col4 = 4 label SUM(Col3) ''"
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決できました